# Set useState to value inside of compent

Tags: reactjs

The code sets the `textCount` to match the input `onChange`, but I need `textCount` to also be set to the value that comes from inside of `App()` from `name`.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function Textarea(props) {
  const [textCount, settextCount] = useState(0);

  const recalculate = (e) => {
    settextCount(e.target.value.length);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <textarea
        type="text"
        onChange={(e) => {
          recalculate(e);
          props.onChange(e);
        }}
      />
      <p>{textCount}/5</p>
    </>
  );
}
export default Textarea;
```

> 

```
const App = (props) => {
const {name} = props.stateData;
  const change = async (e) => {
    props.changevalue(e);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Textarea value={name} onChange={change} />
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Note that `type="text"` isn't needed on a `<textarea>` element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a state inside your Textarea component and set it to its initial value, also initialize the count corresponding:

```
  const [textCount, settextCount] = useState(props.value.length);
  const [textValue, setTextValue] = useState(props.value);
```

Then use the textvalue inside the textarea:

```
  <textarea
    type="text"
    value={textValue}
    onChange={(e) => {
      recalculate(e);
      props.onChange(e);
      setTextValue(e.target.value)
    }}
  />
```

<s>if that is what your looking for here's a working [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-mirzakhani-1dho6e?file=/src/App.js)</s>

**Edit: add the improved sandbox from comments**

[improved version](https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-butterfly-p2k6pk?file=/src/App.js) from @Leland

Comment: This makes it into a controlled component, which is likely the right move. You should remove `textCount` then, as that's derived state. Just use `textValue.length` instead, and remove `recalculate` entirely. It's also worth noting that your approach makes `value` a required prop.

Comment: good catch, you are completely right!

Comment: Here's my slight modification that leaves `value` optional, uses derived state, and uses destructuring instead of accessing `props` directly. The only other thing of note is that the `onChange` callback should fire *after* the state update: https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-butterfly-p2k6pk?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I edited my answer with your sandbox for better visibility. hope that's ok!

Answer (score 0):

The value attribute on form elements will override the value in the DOM. If you want to specify the initial value, but leave subsequent updates uncontrolled, you can specify a defaultValue attribute instead of value.

```
<textarea defaultValue={name} onChange={change} />
```

Comment: Will `textCount` be correct on mount with just this? That's really what OP is asking about.

Comment: Answer: no. Notice that the render incorrectly shows "/5" on mount: https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-bell-z45b2y?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need to have state for `textCount` since the `Textarea` component is going to be re-rendered any time it receives a new value, therefore we can calculate the `length` of the value while rendering.

Also, the `<p>` tag has to be outside the `<textarea>` element, and the `recalculate()` function doesn't seem to be necessary in this case since we can get the `length` just by reading the `length` property from the value.

```
export default function App() {
  const [textValue, setTextValue] = useState("initialValue");
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Textarea value={textValue} onChange={setTextValue}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export function Textarea(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <textarea value={props.value} onChange={(e) => {
        props.onChange(e.target.value)
      }}
      ></textarea>
      <p>textCount: {props.value.length}</p>
    </>
  )
}
```